# What is a correct way to remove old boost version and install new one?

Tags: apt, uninstall, libraries, aptitude, boost

I want to delete `libboost1.54-dev`(which I think was installed via `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev`) and install `libboost1.56-dev`on Ubuntu 14.04.

Seems command `sudo apt-get autoremove libboost1.54-dev` (from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397939/how-to-uninstall-boost-1-49-and-install-boost-1-54-in-ubuntu)) also remove all related packages which is not desireable behaviour:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  freeglut3 icu-devtools libboost-all-dev libboost-atomic-dev
  libboost-atomic1.54-dev libboost-atomic1.54.0 libboost-chrono-dev
  libboost-chrono1.54-dev libboost-chrono1.54.0 libboost-context-dev
  libboost-context1.54-dev libboost-context1.54.0 libboost-coroutine-dev
  libboost-coroutine1.54-dev libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.54-dev
  libboost-dev libboost-exception-dev libboost-exception1.54-dev
  libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.54-dev
  libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0
  libboost-graph1.54-dev libboost-graph1.54.0 libboost-iostreams-dev
  libboost-iostreams1.54-dev libboost-locale-dev libboost-locale1.54-dev
  libboost-locale1.54.0 libboost-log-dev libboost-log1.54-dev
  libboost-log1.54.0 libboost-math-dev libboost-math1.54-dev
  libboost-math1.54.0 libboost-mpi-dev libboost-mpi-python-dev
  libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev libboost-mpi-python1.54.0 libboost-mpi1.54-dev
  libboost-mpi1.54.0 libboost-program-options-dev
  libboost-program-options1.54-dev libboost-program-options1.54.0
  libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.54-dev libboost-python1.54.0
  libboost-random-dev libboost-random1.54-dev libboost-random1.54.0
  libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.54-dev libboost-regex1.54.0
  libboost-serialization-dev libboost-serialization1.54-dev
  libboost-serialization1.54.0 libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.54-dev
  libboost-signals1.54.0 libboost-system-dev libboost-system1.54-dev
  libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.54-dev
  libboost-test1.54.0 libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.54-dev
  libboost-thread1.54.0 libboost-timer-dev libboost-timer1.54-dev
  libboost-timer1.54.0 libboost-tools-dev libboost-wave-dev
  libboost-wave1.54-dev libboost-wave1.54.0 libboost1.54-dev
  libboost1.54-tools-dev libcf0 libcr0 libeigen3-dev libflann-dev libflann1.8
  libgl2ps-dev libgl2ps0 libhwloc-dev libhwloc5 libibverbs-dev libibverbs1
  libicu-dev libnetcdf-dev libnetcdfc++4 libnetcdfc7 libnetcdff5
  libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi1.6 libopenni-dev libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0
  libopenni0 libopenni2-0 libopenni2-dev libpci-dev libpcl-1.7-all
  libpcl-1.7-all-dev libpcl-1.7-bin libpcl-1.7-doc libpcl-all libpcl-apps-1.7
  libpcl-apps-1.7-dev libpcl-common-1.7 libpcl-common-1.7-dev
  libpcl-features-1.7 libpcl-features-1.7-dev libpcl-filters-1.7
  libpcl-filters-1.7-dev libpcl-geometry-1.7-dev libpcl-io-1.7
  libpcl-io-1.7-dev libpcl-kdtree-1.7 libpcl-kdtree-1.7-dev
  libpcl-keypoints-1.7 libpcl-keypoints-1.7-dev libpcl-octree-1.7
  libpcl-octree-1.7-dev libpcl-outofcore-1.7 libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev
  libpcl-people-1.7 libpcl-people-1.7-dev libpcl-recognition-1.7
  libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev libpcl-registration-1.7
  libpcl-registration-1.7-dev libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7
  libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7-dev libpcl-search-1.7 libpcl-search-1.7-dev
  libpcl-segmentation-1.7 libpcl-segmentation-1.7-dev libpcl-surface-1.7
  libpcl-surface-1.7-dev libpcl-tracking-1.7 libpcl-tracking-1.7-dev
  libpcl-visualization-1.7 libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev libqhull-dev libqhull6
  libtorque2 libusb-1.0-0-dev libusb-1.0-doc libvtk5-dev libvtk5-qt4-dev
  libvtk5.8 libvtk5.8-qt4 libxml2-dev libxss-dev mpi-default-bin
  mpi-default-dev openmpi-bin openmpi-common openni-utils tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
```

`sudo apt-get remove libboost1.54-dev` produce something similar:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  freeglut3 icu-devtools libboost-atomic1.54.0 libboost-chrono1.54.0
  libboost-context1.54.0 libboost-filesystem1.54.0
  libboost-graph-parallel1.54.0 libboost-graph1.54.0 libboost-locale1.54.0
  libboost-log1.54.0 libboost-math1.54.0 libboost-mpi-python1.54.0
  libboost-mpi1.54.0 libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-python1.54.0
  libboost-random1.54.0 libboost-regex1.54.0 libboost-serialization1.54.0
  libboost-signals1.54.0 libboost-system1.54.0 libboost-test1.54.0
  libboost-thread1.54.0 libboost-timer1.54.0 libboost-tools-dev
  libboost-wave1.54.0 libboost1.54-tools-dev libcf0 libcr0 libeigen3-dev
  libflann-dev libflann1.8 libgl2ps-dev libgl2ps0 libhwloc-dev libhwloc5
  libibverbs-dev libibverbs1 libicu-dev libnetcdf-dev libnetcdfc++4
  libnetcdfc7 libnetcdff5 libopenmpi-dev libopenmpi1.6 libopenni-dev
  libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0 libopenni0 libopenni2-0 libopenni2-dev
  libpci-dev libpcl-1.7-bin libpcl-1.7-doc libpcl-apps-1.7 libpcl-common-1.7
  libpcl-features-1.7 libpcl-filters-1.7 libpcl-io-1.7 libpcl-kdtree-1.7
  libpcl-keypoints-1.7 libpcl-octree-1.7 libpcl-outofcore-1.7
  libpcl-people-1.7 libpcl-recognition-1.7 libpcl-registration-1.7
  libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7 libpcl-search-1.7 libpcl-segmentation-1.7
  libpcl-surface-1.7 libpcl-tracking-1.7 libpcl-visualization-1.7 libqhull-dev
  libqhull6 libtorque2 libusb-1.0-0-dev libusb-1.0-doc libvtk5-dev
  libvtk5-qt4-dev libvtk5.8 libvtk5.8-qt4 libxml2-dev libxss-dev
  mpi-default-bin mpi-default-dev openmpi-bin openmpi-common openni-utils
  tcl8.6-dev tk8.6-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libboost-all-dev libboost-atomic-dev libboost-atomic1.54-dev
  libboost-chrono-dev libboost-chrono1.54-dev libboost-context-dev
  libboost-context1.54-dev libboost-coroutine-dev libboost-coroutine1.54-dev
  libboost-date-time-dev libboost-date-time1.54-dev libboost-dev
  libboost-exception-dev libboost-exception1.54-dev libboost-filesystem-dev
  libboost-filesystem1.54-dev libboost-graph-dev libboost-graph-parallel-dev
  libboost-graph-parallel1.54-dev libboost-graph1.54-dev
  libboost-iostreams-dev libboost-iostreams1.54-dev libboost-locale-dev
  libboost-locale1.54-dev libboost-log-dev libboost-log1.54-dev
  libboost-math-dev libboost-math1.54-dev libboost-mpi-dev
  libboost-mpi-python-dev libboost-mpi-python1.54-dev libboost-mpi1.54-dev
  libboost-program-options-dev libboost-program-options1.54-dev
  libboost-python-dev libboost-python1.54-dev libboost-random-dev
  libboost-random1.54-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-regex1.54-dev
  libboost-serialization-dev libboost-serialization1.54-dev
  libboost-signals-dev libboost-signals1.54-dev libboost-system-dev
  libboost-system1.54-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-test1.54-dev
  libboost-thread-dev libboost-thread1.54-dev libboost-timer-dev
  libboost-timer1.54-dev libboost-wave-dev libboost-wave1.54-dev
  libboost1.54-dev libpcl-1.7-all libpcl-1.7-all-dev libpcl-all
  libpcl-apps-1.7-dev libpcl-common-1.7-dev libpcl-features-1.7-dev
  libpcl-filters-1.7-dev libpcl-geometry-1.7-dev libpcl-io-1.7-dev
  libpcl-kdtree-1.7-dev libpcl-keypoints-1.7-dev libpcl-octree-1.7-dev
  libpcl-outofcore-1.7-dev libpcl-people-1.7-dev libpcl-recognition-1.7-dev
  libpcl-registration-1.7-dev libpcl-sample-consensus-1.7-dev
  libpcl-search-1.7-dev libpcl-segmentation-1.7-dev libpcl-surface-1.7-dev
  libpcl-tracking-1.7-dev libpcl-visualization-1.7-dev
```

So what is reason of such behaviour? How to remove boost library correctly?

Also I already seen [this qestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application), but in my case for example PCL library is not dependency of boost, but depends on boost, ideally I what update my boost and reinstall PCL at the same time simultaneously, is it possible?

Comment: `libboost1.56-dev` isn't available in the trusty tahr repos.

Comment: @anonymous2 what options we have? build from source?

Comment: Specifically, why do you want 56?